# Why does date_create() behave differently on production then on local vagrant?

Tags: php, vagrant, oxid

I have the following construct of a customer admin backend, which does work fine in production but on local vagrant test [mashine](https://github.com/OXID-eSales/oxvm_eshop) it is running into timeout.(I marked the row from error message in the script with a comment).

I already increased the execution time to 300 from 30 but it hits the same error. So I am assuming the while loop is running endlessly?!

Cause the the tempdate and datetime do not meet the constraint !=
View the timestamps in error logging for this.
I did the same error logging on production
It seems on production the dates are created like this 
(2019-03-28 16:30:14.000000) while on test they have micro seconds as well which are then different and do not match the while criteria of != to break the loop

**Question:**
Can someone please explain why **date_create()** does not give me micro seconds but on test it does causeing the while not work as intended?

```
public $_datefrom = null;
public $_dateto = null;
public function __construct () {

        //(...deleted stuff to post this.....)
        $datetime1 = date_create($this->_datefrom);
        $datetime2 = date_create($this->_dateto);

        $tempdate = date_create($this->_datefrom);
        $tempdateto = new DateTime();

        $this->_aIntervalDateArray[$tempdate->format('d.m.Y')] = array();
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
        while($tempdate != $datetime2) {
        print_r("tempdate "); var_dump($tempdate); print_r(" datetime2 ");var_dump($datetime2);print_r("<br>");// debugging
            $tempdate->modify('+1 day'); // row 119  <<<<<<<<
            if($tempdate <= $tempdateto ) {
                $this->_aIntervalDateArray[$tempdate->format('d.m.Y')] = array();
            }
        }

        $this->_datefrompast = $datetime1->modify('-1 year')->format('Y-m-d');
        $this->_datetopast = $datetime2->modify('-1 year')->format('Y-m-d');


        $datetime1_past = date_create($this->_datefrompast);
        $datetime2_past = date_create($this->_datetopast);

        $tempdatePast = date_create($this->_datefrompast);

        $this->_aIntervalDateArrayPast[$tempdatePast->format('d.m.Y')] = array();

        while($tempdatePast != $datetime2_past) {
            $tempdatePast->modify('+1 day');
            if($tempdatePast <= $datetime2_past ) {
                $this->_aIntervalDateArrayPast[$tempdatePast->format('d.m.Y')] = array();
            }
        }

        $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

        $this->_dateinterval = $this->days_between() + 1;

        $this->_user = $oUser = $this->getUser();

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> [28 Mar 14:14:48.572803 2019] [uncaught error] [type E_ERROR] [file
>   /var/www/oxideshop/source/modules/comp/gg_analytics/application/controllers/admin/admin_gganalytics_view.php]
>   [line 119] [code ] [message Maximum execution time of 300 seconds
>   exceeded]

Error logging:

```
tempdate
/var/www/oxideshop/source/modules/comp/gg_analytics/application/controllers/admin/admin_gganalytics_view.php:145:
object(DateTime)[38]
  public 'date' => string '2019-03-28 15:13:20.613671' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)

datetime2

/var/www/oxideshop/source/modules/comp/gg_analytics/application/controllers/admin/admin_gganalytics_view.php:145:
object(DateTime)[37]
  public 'date' => string '2019-03-28 15:13:20.613669' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)


tempdate

/var/www/oxideshop/source/modules/comp/gg_analytics/application/controllers/admin/admin_gganalytics_view.php:145:
object(DateTime)[38]
  public 'date' => string '2019-03-29 15:13:20.613671' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)

datetime2

/var/www/oxideshop/source/modules/comp/gg_analytics/application/controllers/admin/admin_gganalytics_view.php:145:
object(DateTime)[37]
  public 'date' => string '2019-03-28 15:13:20.613669' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)
```

Comment: Are you using the same PHP version in both environments? The `date_create()` is an alias for [DateTime::__construct()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) and on that page it says: _"PHP 7.1 - From now on microseconds are filled with actual value. Not with '00000'."_

Comment: Ah I ok, I changed my Vagrant some time ago on 7.1 cause the managed host said they will drop 5.6 support. But as I see now, php 7.0 is running there. Thank you!